I need help removing an icon that I don't recognize in the code
I'm new to Swift and I'm building my first app, as you can see in the image, there are two "chevron.right" icons, but one is smaller and is attached to the margin of the card, in the code I only added this one:
Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
    .foregroundColor(.gray)

I don't know where the other icon comes from, I imagine it's a property of the NavigationLink, but I'm not sure, could you help me remove it?
                                HStack(spacing: 16) {
                                    ZStack {
                                        Circle()
                                            .fill(mainColor.opacity(0.1))
                                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                        Image(systemName: "cube.box.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(mainColor)
                                            .font(.title2)
                                    }
                                    
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                        Text(item.itemDescription)
                                            .font(.headline)
                                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                            .lineLimit(1)
                                        
                                        HStack {
                                            Label(item.brand.isEmpty ? "N/A" : item.brand, systemImage: "tag.fill")
                                                .font(.subheadline)
                                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                                .lineLimit(1)
                                            
                                            Spacer()
                                            
                                            Label(item.conditionO.isEmpty ? "N/A" : item.conditionO, systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.subheadline)
                                                .foregroundColor(
                                                    item.conditionO.lowercased() == "new" ? .green :
                                                    item.conditionO.lowercased() == "used" ? .orange : .gray
                                                )
                                                .lineLimit(1)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .padding(.leading, 8)
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                                .padding(.vertical, 12)
                            } ```


Assuming you do have a NavigationLink (I don't see any in your code), then yes that is automatically added by the NavigationLink. See my answer here on ways around it.

Yes all the code in the question is inside a NavigationLink, I tried your answer but it doesnt work :(

Please show a [mcve] of how you applied the answer. It should be some code that I can directly copy and paste into a new project and see how it "doesn't work".

try using NavigationStack instead of NavigationView
